# Extracting data from a table that has no name or id

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that enters in this adress ( https://processual.trf1.jus.br/consultaProcessual/numeroProcesso.php?secao=TRF1&enviar=ok ) and fill in the blank with a number ( 1778390520174019198 for example ). After that, my code clicks on the 'pesquisar button'. Then, my code clicks on 'partes'.

After that, there it is the information I need. In this example it's ( requerente - Jamille Seixas Souza ).

I couldn't figure a way to put this data in my excel worksheet. Please help me!
This is my code until now.

```
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim C
Dim numero As String
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim objlink As Object
Dim objElementCol As Object
Dim objElement As Object
Dim objeto As Object


numero = Application.InputBox("Por Favor entre com o numero precatorio", "", "")


Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate "https://processual.trf1.jus.br/consultaProcessual/numeroProcesso.php?secao=TRF1&enviar=ok"

ieBusy ie

ie.Document.all("proc").innerText = numero
'obtém o forma a qual o controle de login pertence para submetê-lo
ie.Document.getElementById("enviar").Click

ieBusy ie

Dim elemUnique, elemCollection As Object
Set elemCollection = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")
For Each elemUnique In elemCollection

If elemUnique.innerText Like "Partes" Then
    elemUnique.Click
    Exit For
End If                          
Next elemUnique
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, let me see. Here

```
ie.Document.all("proc").innerText = numero
```

You are probably trying to type some value into textbox. It should be:

```
Dim iInputBox As IHTMLElement
Set iInputBox = ie.Document.getElementById("proc")
iInputBox.Value = numero
```

Then you are trying to click button. This is ok, but you should give your application some time to load the site. Add a piece of code

```
Do Until ie.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop
```

Maybe your function ie.busy do the same, I don't know, it doesn't work for me. Then we have a little problem, I don't know how the site with results looks like, I have typed 1234567890 into inputbox and this sent me to nowhere. When I have typed the number 1778390520174019198 some script run without end. This may be because I am behind firewall. But if there is only one table in site that displays after clicking "Pesquisar", this code should be able to get it.

```
Dim iTab As IHTMLElement
Dim iTr As IHTMLElement
Dim iTd As IHTMLElement
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lColumn As Long

Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)) 'lets give script some time to execute
Set iTab = ie.Document.getElementById("aba-processo")
lRow = 1
For Each iTr In iTab.getElementsByTagName("tr")
    lColumn = 1
    For Each iTd In iTr.getElementsByTagName("td")
        Cells(lRow, lColumn).Value = iTd.innerText
        lColumn = lColumn + 1
    Next iTd
    lRow = lRow + 1
Next iTr
```

On the end, you should close IE.

```
ie.Quit
```

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Its actually the third (3) table in the site, how can I do it?

Comment: help please hahahahhaa

Comment: if it always the third just tell it to the application: Set iTab = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("table")(2)

Comment: It not working, could you please try to acess the link to get the exact location of the table? https://processual.trf1.jus.br/consultaProcessual/numeroProcesso.php?secao=TRF1&enviar=ok and the number to fill is 1778390520174019198